# How can I determine whether my variety is toric or not?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, toric-geometry

Assume throughout that $X$ is a normal rational variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Is there a way to determine whether or not $X$ is a toric variety? I am particularly interested in the following examples.

1) $X$ is an affine hypersurface of dimension 3 (e.g. $V(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^3 + T^3) \subset \mathbb{A}^4)$

2) $X$ is an affine hypersurface $(\dim X \geq 2$)

3) $X$ is a projective hypersurface $(\dim X \geq 2$)

4) $X$ is a weighted projective hypersurface in weighted projective space $(\dim X \geq 2$)

Comment: A necessary condition for a variety being toric is that the variety has to be rational. This can help you to eliminate a large class of the examples you listed.

Comment: @AGlearner Yes, I already assumed this in the first sentence.